# Build ReactNative Code for IOS and Android Platform

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, cross-platform

**Build and Run React-Native Codebase on IOS and Android Platform**

What are the basic commands required to run react native code on IOS and Android Platform

Answer (score 0):

Steps to Run App on Android and IOS platform

1) Checkout from Repository
2) Goto project directory
3) Run 
`npm install`

4) Run
`react-native run-android` to run app on Android Devices
`react-native run-ios` to run app on IOS Simulator

**Android Specific :**

React-Native Prepare unsigned APK :

You need to manually create the bundle for a debug build.

Bundle debug build:

Run :

`react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug`

Create debug build:

`cd android`

Then

`./gradlew assembleDebug`

Generated apk will be located at `android/app/build/outputs/apk`

**IOS Specific**

You need to manually create the bundle for a debug build.

Run : 
`react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios`

Go to `XCode` open Xcodeproject file

Go to `Product` -> `Archive` in Xcode and follow the steps based on your desired release

Be

Done !!!